# Redirect after save Doctrine 1.2 Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

i want to redirect the action "new" to action "edit" passing the id generated. I take the url very well but the page don't go to redirection, and stay on same page.

This is my code:

```
if ($form->isValid())
{
    $form->save();
    $id = $form->getObject()->getId();

    $var = $this->redirect('/admin/noticiascadastros/editar/'.$id);
    return $var;
}
```

This is my http headers.
[image]

Comment: What http headers did you get?

Comment: And btw are you sure your form values are valid ? =)

Comment: i get: 
Connection Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=97
Transfer-Encoding chunked

Comment: That information is not enough, please provide (update your question) full list of headers.

Comment: i'll edit my question with an printscreen of http headers.

Comment: Apparently, there is no `Location` header which make redirect.

Comment: Try to debug on which side this appear (it might be issues with web server). Just add these lines before `$this->redirect ...` call:
`header("Location: /noticiascadastros/editar/$id");
exit;`

Comment: now i get Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:8089/noticiascadastros/editar/10917 on debug mode.

Comment: sorry, i edit you header(location), and now i get status 200 OK, but not refresh the page, stuck at same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94708/discussion-between-kirugan-and-estacio-di-fabio).